# RNetLogo not working on macOS Sierra and Windows

Tags: r, windows, netlogo, macos-sierra, rjava

I am using macOS Sierra and R version 3.4.1 and java version "1.8.0_144". I am trying a simple example adapted from the RNetLogo manual:

```
require(RNetLogo)
require(tidyverse)
require(extrafont)
loadfonts()

nl.path <- "/Applications/NetLogo 6.0.1"
NLStart(nl.path)
model.path <- "/models/Sample Models/Earth Science/Fire.nlogo"
absolute.model.path <- paste(nl.path,model.path,sep="")
NLLoadModel(absolute.model.path)
```

But the command NLLoadModel gives the following error:

```
Error in .jcall(nl.obj, "V", "loadModel", .jnew("java/lang/String", model.path)) : 
  RcallMethod: invalid object parameter
```

This also happens in Windows also with Java version 1.8.

Comment: On Windows, at least, I had call `NLStart` using `NLStart(nl.path, gui = FALSE, nl.jarname = "netlogo-6.0.1.jar")` (although the `gui` setting can be `TRUE` or `FALSE`). Not sure if it's the same on Mac. The complete setup that worked for me is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056013/loading-a-netlogo-model-with-extension-from-rnetlogo/45085264#45085264)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fire.nlogo model in macOS Sierra, I found two solutions (see the manual of RNetLogo):
First, with gui=FALSE

```
Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)
require(RNetLogo)
nl.path <- "/Applications/NetLogo 6.0.1/Java"
nl.path2 <- "/Applications/NetLogo 6.0.1"
NLStart(nl.path, gui=FALSE, nl.jarname='netlogo-6.0.1.jar')
model.path <- "/models/Sample Models/Earth Science/Fire.nlogo"
absolute.model.path <- paste(nl.path2,model.path,sep="")
NLLoadModel(absolute.model.path)
# Fire from manual
NLCommand("setup")
NLDoCommand(10, "go")
burned <- NLReport("burned-trees")
print(burned)
NLQuit()
```

Then with gui=TRUE:

```
Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)
require(JGR)
Sys.unsetenv("NOAWT")
JGR()
# Now using JGR
require(RNetLogo)
nl.path <- "/Applications/NetLogo 6.0.1/Java"
nl.path2 <- "/Applications/NetLogo 6.0.1"
NLStart(nl.path, gui=TRUE, nl.jarname='netlogo-6.0.1.jar')
model.path <- "/models/Sample Models/Earth Science/Fire.nlogo"
absolute.model.path <- paste(nl.path2,model.path,sep="")
NLLoadModel(absolute.model.path)
# Fire from manual
NLCommand("setup")
NLDoCommand(10, "go")
burned <- NLReport("burned-trees")
print(burned)
NLQuit()
```